# Rails 3 Unexpected Callback Behavior in STI model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, associations, sti

Can't figure out why this would be happening:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :belongable, :polymorphic => true

  def after_save 
    if belongable.kind_of?(User)
      send(:some_method)
    end
  end
end

class Bar < Foo

  def some_method
    #Do something
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :belongings, :as => :belongable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :belongings, :as => :belongable
end
```

The class 'Bar' is an STI model that inherits from Foo (Foo has a 'type' attr). Both Groups and Users are able to have many Bars.

The following works as expected (some_method doesn't get called):

```
g = Group.create
g.belongings << Bar.new
g.save
```

The following calls some_method:

```
Group.first.belongings.first.update_attributes(:attr => :val)
```

How/Why?! Why isn't the condition in the 'after_save' callback being evaluated once the association already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"some_method" can't be called "update"... :-/

AR objects already define a method called update (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) and this method get's called when you call 'update_attributes'.

Answer (score 0):

`Group.create.belongings << Bar.new` never saves Bar to the database. So `after_save` is never called. The second example uses `update_attributes` which does save to the database. That is why it triggers `after_save`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But why does the condition in the callback evaluate to true and therefore call 'some_method' when the class of the parent is Group not User?

Answer (score 0):

This is a mix of STI and Polymorphism. Your Foo model should have belongable_type and belongable_id attributes.

I am not exactly able to shoot it down, but changing your comparison to this should work :

```
belongable_type == "User"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this to no avail.